ReferenceError when I put fullRepresentation
I'm trying to create a Plasmoid (Plasma 6) I need fullRepresentation and compactRepresentation to display dynamically generated switches, for now I'm working on fullRepresentation
if I put this :
  fullRepresentation: ColumnLayout {
    id: fullRoot
    Repeater {

I have this error :
qml: Toggling action for: isMain_666 to true
qml: Executing command: isMain_666|sleep 2; exit 1
qml: New data from switch: isMain_666 for command: sleep 2; exit 1 with data: [object Object]
file:///home/xkain/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/com.xkain.Ultimat-ToggleSwitch/contents/ui/main.qml:32: ReferenceError: switchRepeater is not defined

But if I remove "fullRepresentation:" everything works perfectly:
  ColumnLayout {
         id:fullRoot
         Repeater {

here is the complete code:
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls

import org.kde.plasma.plasmoid
import org.kde.plasma.core as PlasmaCore
import org.kde.plasma.plasma5support as Plasma5Support
import org.kde.plasma.components as PlasmaComponents3
import org.kde.kirigami as Kirigami

PlasmoidItem {
    id: root

    readonly property var switches: JSON.parse(Plasmoid.configuration.switches)
    Plasmoid.backgroundHints: PlasmaCore.Types.DefaultBackground | PlasmaCore.Types.ConfigurableBackground

    preferredRepresentation: fullRepresentation


    Plasma5Support.DataSource {
        id: executable
        engine: "executable"
        connectedSources: []

        onNewData: function(sourceName, data) {
            var parts = sourceName.split('|');  // Split the source name to retrieve switchId and the command
            var switchId = parts[0];
            console.log("New data from switch:", switchId, "for command:", parts[1], "with data:", data);

            for (var i = 0; i < root.switches.length; ++i) {
                if (switches[i].switchId === switchId) {
                    var switchDelegate = switchRepeater.itemAt(i);
                    if (!switchDelegate) {
                        console.error("Switch delegate not found for switchId:", switchId);
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (data['exit code'] != 0) {
                        switchDelegate.checked = !switchDelegate.checked;
                    }

                    disconnectSource(sourceName);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }


        function exec(switchId, cmd) {
            var commandWithId = switchId + "|" + cmd;
            console.log("Executing command:", commandWithId);
            connectSource(commandWithId);
        }
    }

    function toggleAction(switchId, checked) {
        console.log("Toggling action for:", switchId, "to", checked);
        for (var i = 0; i < switches.length; ++i) {
            if (switches[i].switchId === switchId) {
                switches[i].checked = checked;
                var script = checked ? switches[i].onScript : switches[i].offScript;
                executable.exec(switchId, script);

                if (switches[i].isMaster) {
                    // Toggle all isMain below this master until next master or end of list
                    toggleDependentSwitches(i, checked);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    function toggleDependentSwitches(masterIndex, checked) {
        console.log("Toggling dependent switches for master index:", masterIndex, "to", checked);
        for (var i = masterIndex + 1; i < switches.length; i++) {
            if (switches[i].isMaster) break; // Stop if another master is found
            if (switches[i].positionByMaster) {
                switches[i].checked = checked;
                var delegate = switchRepeater.itemAt(i);
                if (delegate) {
                    delegate.checked = checked;
                    var script = checked ? switches[i].onScript : switches[i].offScript;
                    executable.exec(switches[i].switchId, script);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fullRepresentation: ColumnLayout {
        id: fullRoot
        Repeater {
            id: switchRepeater
            model: root.switches
            delegate: PlasmaComponents3.Switch {
                id: switchItem
                text: modelData.name
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
                checked: modelData.defaultPosition
                onCheckedChanged: {
                    root.toggleAction(modelData.switchId, switchItem.checked);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    compactRepresentation: {}
}

How can I fix this error? I'm just starting to learn programming so I certainly made a mistake somewhere but I'm stuck.
